# regex into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split, match

I have a php script to split an address into an array:

```
$address = 'ADDRESS';
$pattern = '#^([a-zA-Z0-9 \'-]*) ([0-9\-0-9]{1,10})([a-zA-Z0-9\-/ ]{0,})$#';
$address_details = array();

preg_match($pattern,$address, $address_details);
```

This script works fine, however, I want to use the same thing in a javascript function. I have tried this

```
var address = 'ADDRESS';    
var pattern = '#^([a-zA-Z0-9 \'-]*) ([0-9\-0-9]{1,10})([a-zA-Z0-9\-/ ]{0,})$#';
var address_details = address.match(pattern);
```

This does not work and returns null on address_details. The aim is to be able to call address_details[1] and address_details[2]

Comment: JS regex needs `/.../` regex delimiters: `var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 '-]*) ([0-9-]{1,10})([a-zA-Z0-9\/ -]*)$/;` and (no quotes around). Please provide sample input.

Comment: That is, you can't just copy paste a regex  between JS and PHP, they are slightly different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript regex requires `/.../` regex delimiters, and then, no quotes can appear around this *regex literal notation*. Also, your pattern can be enhanced a bit:

```
var pattern = /^([A-Z0-9 '-]*) ([0-9-]{1,10})([A-Z0-9\/ -]*)$/i;
```

No need to repeat `[0-9]` inside `[0-9\-0-9]`, the hyphen at the end of the character class does not have to be escape, `[a-zA-Z]` can be reduced to `[a-z]` with `/i` case-insensitive modifier and `{0,}` limiting quantifier is equal to `*` one.

See JS demo:

```js
var address = 'Address 1 1234567890/Text-Here1 and here';    
var pattern = /^([A-Z0-9 '-]*) ([0-9-]{1,10})([A-Z0-9\/ -]*)$/i;
var address_details = address.match(pattern);
document.body.innerHTML = "Group 1: " + address_details[1] + "<br/>Group 2: " + address_details[2] + "<br/>Group 3: " + address_details[3];
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since now you have this privilege.